# Should we help others reinvent the wheel?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I've seen a lot of people asking us to review their DBAL, or MVC framework, or templating system, etc. While I totally support these people's efforts as a good way to learn, I think answering such involved questions could be a huge drain on the community.

On that note, would an acceptable answer be "see vendor X's code", or should we try to answer *all* questions, regardless of how novel they are?

Comment: I think “see this code” is not an acceptable answer. A review should be about specific issues in the original code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel can actually be a useful exercise. But letting someone reinvent the wheel when they don't know they are doing it is a problem.

Pointing out that a ready-made solutions exists is helpful part of an answer. But you should still provide a review of the code itself. If you don't want to can't, you should probably just leave a comment pointing to wheel's website. Just posting an answer saying to use that wheel isn't really a code review.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) that can be used to signal to others that the asker knows that they're asking for help reimplementing something.